# use multiple functions in one script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this probablt been asked a lot, but I couldnt find something that worked for me.

I want integrate two script into one, and havent had any luck. whats the correct way to do this?

The scripts:

```
$('document').ready(
    function() {
        function _title() {
            var allow = document.title.search("Inloggen / Infotheek Portal -");
            if (allow > -1) {
                window.location.assign("http://ccp.infotheek.com/m4n?oid=etailer-status")
            }
        }
        window.onload = _title;
    });



$('document').ready(
    function() {
        function _title() {
            var allow = document.title.search("Infotheek Portal -");
            if (allow > -1) {
                document.getElementById('newbutton').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        window.onload = _title;
    });
```

Comment: `if (condition #1) { do stuff for #1 } else if (condition #2) { do stuff for #2 }`

Comment: ^^^ Good advice. Or change one of the function names from _title to _title2 or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to assign to the `window.onload` handler, just perform all your logic on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var allow = document.title.search("Inloggen / Infotheek Portal -");
    if(allow>-1) {
        window.location.assign("http://ccp.infotheek.com/m4n?oid=etailer-status") 
    }

    allow = document.title.search("Infotheek Portal -");
    if(allow>-1){
        document.getElementById('newbutton').style.display="block";
    }
});
```

If you really want to run this in `window.onload` then just replace the following line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
```

Comment: what if he has other code that calls function _title?

Comment: His `function _title()` is declared locally in the `$(document).ready()` function scope, so it is not available outside of that context.